# AWK command to compare two files, report row of first file if not found in second file, report row of second file if found

Tags: unix

I have a basic level of unix understanding, so this problem might be easy.

I have been trying to use the "awk" command to compare two files (two columns in each file separated by a tab), with the ultimate goal of having a file with all the rows of file 1, but if the row is found in file 2, I would like the row of file 1 to be replaced with that same row from file 2.

```
File 1: 
Supercontig_12.1,420    0
Supercontig_12.1,421    0
Supercontig_12.1,422    0
Supercontig_12.1,423    0
…(rows continue in numerical order)
Supercontig_12.1,428    0
Supercontig_12.1,429    0
Supercontig_12.1,430    0

File 2 (not in numerical order): 
Supercontig_12.1,422    0.6
Supercontig_12.1,426    0.333333
Supercontig_12.1,428    0.5
Supercontig_12.1,429    0
```

desired output

```
Output: 
Supercontig_12.1,420    0
Supercontig_12.1,421    0
Supercontig_12.1,422    0.6
Supercontig_12.1,423    0.333333
…
Supercontig_12.1,428    0.5
Supercontig_12.1,429    0
Supercontig_12.1,430    0
```

I have been using the following command, but all it does is add the rows of file 2 to the end of the rows of file 1, much like the "cat" command.

```
$ awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]} $1 in a{print $1 "\t" $2}' file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt
```

I know I am making an array the size of file 1, which is what I would like to do, but I'm not selecting for the file 2 data within that array.  Any help would be most welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Andy

Comment: Can file2 have records missing in file1? Is the value in file1 always 0?

Comment: Hi Walter, Thank you for your questions.  To answer, the second column in file1 is always a zero, as I am trying to input data to a "blank" column, and no, the records in file2 will always be found in file1, it's just that file1 may have rows not found in file2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When all lines have the same length (not `Supercontig_12.1,420` and `Supercontig_12.1,4202`) you can `grep` and `cut`:
You can get the first field of file2 with

```
cut -f1 file2.txt
```

The output of this command can be used as if it is a file with process substitution `<(some_command)`.
To remove these lines from file1.txt

```
grep -vf <(cut -f1 file2.txt) file1.txt
```

Put this together with file2 and sort the result

```
cat file2.txt <(grep -vf <(cut -f1 file2.txt) file1.txt) |sort
```

What is wrong with your `awk`?

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]} $1 in a{print $1 "\t" $2}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

When parsing file1.txt, you do not want to print anything. Use `next`. And store $0:

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{print $1 "\t" $2}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

When $1 from file2.txt is found in `a`, replace the value (don't print yet)

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{a[$1]=$0}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

When everything is parsed, print content of array.

```
awk -F"\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} $1 in a{a[$1]=$0} END { for (i in a) print a[i] } ' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Walter!  Your suggestion worked almost perfectly.  The only issue: the output file from your print array isn't sorted numerically, and appear fairly randomly in groups.  I tried to "sort -n -k1" the file, but then the numbers after the comma increase from ",1" to ",10" to ",100" to ",1000" to ",1001"…  Is there a way to either print the columns sorted numerically, or do a secondary command within sort to put them numerically?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think I got it, Walter (I should have done a bit more research prior to typing my response).  The command 'sort -t "," -k2n output_file.txt' works to do what I want.  Regardless, you helped me out immensely with your nicely detailed explanation.  Thank you for all of your time you put into it!